# How to group by multiple columns in h2o frame?

Tags: h2o, automl, h2o.ai

I have a monthly timeseries dataframe grouped by date and team name. I want to convert it to a h2o frame to run the automl models but the index gets dropped in hf_train. How do I group this data in h2o so that the model runs per team?

```
data=[
['01/01/18','A','Team A',1.5,8.9,'Pop'],
['02/01/18','A','Team AA',1.5,8.9,'Pop'],
['03/01/18','A','Team AA',3.1,11,'Div'],
['04/01/18','A','Team AC',1.5,6,'Div'],
['01/01/18','A','Team A',1.5,8.9,'Pop'],
['02/01/18','A','Team BA',1.5,8.9,'Pop'],
['03/01/18','A','Team BA',3.1,11,'Div'],
['04/01/18','A','Team BC',1.5,6,'Div'],
['01/01/18','C','Team C',1.5,8.9,'Pop'],
['02/01/18','C','Team CA',1.5,8.9,'Pop'],
['03/01/18','C','Team CC',3.1,11,'Div'],
['04/01/18','C','Team CA',1.5,6,'Div']
]

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=['Dt','Co','Team','Val1','Val2','Type'])
df =df.set_index(['Dt','Co'])


import h2o
h2o.init()

hf_train = h2o.H2OFrame(df)
hf_train
```

H2o Automl

```
aml = H2OAutoML(max_runtime_secs = 600, seed = 42)

aml.train(x = x, 
          y = y,
          training_frame = hf_train,
          leaderboard_frame = hf_test)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use pandas' `groupby` to create the H2OFrames.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Dt','Co','Team','Val1','Val2','Type'])
frames = df.groupby(["Dt", "Team"]).apply(h2o.H2OFrame)
automls = dict()

for key, training_frame in frames.items():
    aml = H2OAutoML(max_runtime_secs = 10, seed = 42)
    aml.train(x = x, y = y, training_frame = training_frame, ...)
    automls[key] = aml
```

It's possible I misunderstood the question and you want to split the folds in cross-validation by `Team`, if that's the case, you can use the [`fold_column`](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/fold_column.html) parameter.